# PasteSpecial xlPasteValues - Correct integration inside VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

Good evening friends. I have a really stupid request to which I can't find the correct solution.
I need to insert, in the procedure that you can see below, the **".PasteSpecial xlPasteValues"** parameter in the correct way, to have only values to be pasted in the destination workbook.
The below procedure works fine and I would not change it if possible, but integrate it with the parameter mentioned above.
Unless I change the code and use other solutions. I repeat, the code below is now tested and I use it safely, but now the need to paste the cell format and validations of the original workbook is no longer needed.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Edit:

I'll try to be clearer. I know there are similar requests already resolved. My question is where to put the ".PasteSpecial xlPasteValues" parameter correctly in the procedure that I use already. The other solutions do not paste data into a table, while I use a source and destination table.

```
Public Sub CopyOnMasterDB ()

Dim CopyFrom As Range
Dim Copyto As Range

Set CopyFrom = Workbooks ("FromFile.xlsm"). Worksheets ("Database"). UsedRange.Offset (2, 0)
Set Copyto = Workbooks ("MASTER_DATABASE.xlsx"). Worksheets (1) .Range ("A" & Rows.count) .End (xlUp) .Offset (1, 0) 'Error If I insert .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

CopyFrom .Copy Destination: = Copyto 'Error If I insert .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Workbooks ("MASTER_DATABASE.xlsx"). Close SaveChanges: = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
CopyFrom.Copy Destination:=CopyTo
```

to

```
CopyFrom.Copy
CopyTo.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: BigBen! Simple, fast. The solution I was looking for. In fact I said that my request was "stupid" but that it made me stop. Thanks BigBen!

Comment: BigBen, I believe there is a misunderstanding. I edited my request to be clearer. Finally, I voted for your solution. I did not repeat the request. At least I think so. If I made a mistake I apologize but it was not my intention.

Comment: It's `Range.PasteSpecial`. If you're going to paste special you need one line to copy, and a second line to paste.